# Issue in set the cut-div on image

Tags: html, css

I've created `cut div` from both let and right side with css and I want to set that half div on the image. But due to `border-color:white` the cut part is  not coming transparent. I've tried to give the `border-color:transparent` but it does not work, instead it removes the cut portion... What should be the problem to make it transparent?

**Here is my code:**

```css
.goldenstrip::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-bottom: 106px solid white;
 border-right: 40px solid #c1b07a;
 width: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.goldenstrip::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-top: 106px solid white;
 border-left: 40px solid #c1b07a;
 width: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.goldenstrip {
 text-align: center !important;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #C1B07A;
 color: white;
 font-size: 24px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 38px 0px;
 position: relative;
 font-family: "Roboto Medium";z-index: 1;
  top: 52px;
  width: 90%;
}
.seminar_image img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="goldenstrip">Hello world</span>
<div class="seminar_image"><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" alt="" class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this css instead of your `after` and `before` css.

```
goldenstrip::after {

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -22px;
    width: 45px;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: skew(23deg);
    background: #c1b07a;
    }
    .goldenstrip::before {

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -22px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #c1b07a;
    transform: skew(23deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform` property for a slanted edge div.

```css
.goldenstrip::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #c1b07a;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.goldenstrip::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #c1b07a;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.goldenstrip {
  text-align: center !important;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #C1B07A;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 38px 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Roboto Medium";
  z-index: 1;
  top: 52px;
  width: 90%;
}

.seminar_image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="goldenstrip">Hello world</span>
<div class="seminar_image"><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" alt="" class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linear-gradient and multiple background to create the shape and avoid any extra element:

```css
.goldenstrip {
  text-align: center !important;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 38px 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Roboto Medium";
  z-index: 1;
  top: 52px;
  width: 90%;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 49%, #C1B07A 50%) left/ 30px 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49%, #C1B07A 50%) right/ 30px 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(#C1B07A, #C1B07A) center/calc(100% - 60px) 100% no-repeat;
}

.seminar_image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="goldenstrip">Hello world</span>
<div class="seminar_image"><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" alt="" class=""></div>
```